# I need to get the input value (True/False) of a checkbox when a button is pressed

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to get the input value (true/false) of a checkbox with .setName(chk_id), when id is the id of the row which i have introduced in flexTable cell bycell.
But i always get "e.parameter_"undefined"" becouse e.parameter.chk_i is **"undefined"**

```
var flexTableReg = app.createFlexTable().setId("flexTableReg").setBorderWidth(1);
var check = new Array(lastRow);

for(var r = 0; r < lastRow; r++){
  for(var c = 0; c < lastCol; c++){
    var text = rowsToConfirm[r][c].toString();//HERE IS THE CELL
    flexTableReg.setText(r+1, c, text);


  }
  var id = rowsToConfirm[r][0];
  check[r] = app.createCheckBox().setName("chk_"+id).setId("chk_"+id);
  flexTableReg.setWidget(r+1, lastCol, check[r]);
}//end fors
}//end if

 var botMod = app.createButton().setText("Activar").setId("botStatus");
 var botHandle =  app.createServerHandler("changeStatus").addCallbackElement(verticalPanelAdmin);
 botMod.addClickHandler(botHandle);

mainPanelAdmin.add(flexTableReg);
mainPanelAdmin.add(botMod);
verticalPanelAdmin.add(mainPanelAdmin);
absolutePanelAdmin.add(verticalPanelAdmin);
app.add(absolutePanelAdmin);

return app;
}

function changeStatus(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(LOGS_SHEET_ID);
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var datarray = getDataArray();
  var lastRow = ss.getLastRow();

  for(var i =0; i<=lastRow;i++ ){
    try{
      var par =  e.parameter["chk_"+i];


      if(true){
        stop_if_true
        var row = getRowByID(0,lastRow,i);
         ss.getRange("E"+i).setValue("1");
      }//end if     
    }catch(e){e.parameter_"undefined"  //if e.parameter "undefined"
          return app;}
}//end for
 return app;
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `var id = rowsToConfirm[r][0];` is returning, but that is what you're using as the original id parameter when setting the .setName() and .setId() properties.

When you try to get the values in the callback function you use a numeric `i` param so that could clash.

Second, the return value of a checkbox is always a string so check for `'true'` or `'false'` instead of `true` or `false`.

hope this helps,

Greets.

Comment: yes id = rowsToConfirm[r][0] setNme and setId like chk_1 chk_2 etc.. i will try  to check for 'true' 'false'(string) instead of true, false.

Comment: never reaches the IF function. Always fails: 

var par =  e.parameter["chk_"+i];

I cheked my html code and my buttons getName correctly but my event (e) fails to take parameters and jumps to catch.

Comment: I think my adcallback function is not working becouse my buttons have rigth id like chk_1, chk_2 but the problem is when i try to catch the object with w.parameter.chk_1 or chk_2..

Comment: Before you try to get the e.parameter["chk_"+i], try to take a look at the variable 'e' with the debugger. this way you can have a look at what 'e' does contain. Maybe this will help you to determine what happens and thus what could be the problem.

Comment: nothing happend, i think it is imposible to get `e.parameter` of a multiple checkbox created with name ["chk_"+i] within checkbox in for function.

Comment: come on!! 1 week ^^ somebody??

Comment: asked:
20 days ago

viewed:
76 times

Active:
20 days ago

and no one can answer